# ASP.NET MVC 5 Nullable boolean as dropdown - parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a nullable bool in my model

```
public bool? Property { get; set; }
```

And I render it via `EditorFor`

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Property)
```

How can I add class `form-control` to rendered select and how can I localize strings `Not set`, `True` and `False`? Or better how can I replace them with custom strings?

Comment: You cannot change the values unless you want to create you own template (thats built into the source code). Which version of MVC? (you can only add html attributes using `EditorFor()` in MVC-5.1+)

Comment: probably 5.2.3
`<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />`

Comment: In that case `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Property, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })`. But if you want custom strings, you will need to create a custom `EditorTemplate`, or use `DropDownListFor()` where the `SelectList` contains the 3 possible values.

Comment: I dont understand, can you give me some advice how can I create it?

Comment: Using the `DropDownListFor()` method?

Answer (score 2):

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Property, new SelectList(new[]
                {
                    new SelectListItem { Value = null, Text = "Not set" },
                    new SelectListItem { Value = false, Text = "False" },
                    new SelectListItem { Value = true, Text = "True" },
                },
                "Value",
                "Text"
                ),
         new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Why in the world are you creating a 2nd identical  `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from the 1st one using `new SelectList()` (it's pointless extra overhead)?

Comment: And see the comment to the answer by Jaimin Dave

Answer (score 2):

```
  You can try with below code:  

         @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Property, 
                    new List<SelectListItem>(){                       
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "False", Text = "False" },
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "True", Text = "True" }
    },"Not set",new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: This does not work either. The property is `bool?` so the `value` attribues need to be `null`, `true` and `false` (not `0` and `1`)

Comment: And remove the 3rd `"Select"` parameter (have 2 `null` options makes no sense)

Comment: rather i like to change "Select" to "Not Set" and remove first ListItem.

Comment: And perhaps you should explain that OP can change the `Text` values (e.g. `Text = "Yes"`) - which is what they asked for :)